# Adding new element to array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection like this:-

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("52174bcb834806830e5447"),
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "admin"
        },
        {
            "role": "user"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add a new 'role' to the `roles` array. Like this `{"role": "guest" }`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [$push-operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/)

This should work:

```
 db.collection.update(
     { _id:  ObjectId("52174bcb834806830e5447") },
     { $push: { roles: { role: "guest" } } }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you may use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) to avoid duplicates.