# How to add new object to existing data in mongo

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, insert-update, findandmodify

I have a document like this on my table **UserCollection**:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Mohammad",
  "LastName": "Waheed", 
}
```

I want to add another array object to it how can I do that.?

```
  "PhoneNumbers":[  //this object is not present in the table
        {
          "number": NumberInt(8332045764) 
        },
        {
          "number": NumberInt(1234567890) 
        } 
     ]
```

My expected result is like this:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Mohammad",
  "LastName": "Waheed",
  "PhoneNumbers":[  
        {
          "number": NumberInt(8332045764) 
        },
        {
          "number": NumberInt(1234567890) //when i call this method again it should store like this
        } 
     ] 
}
```

This is what I have tried :
1.only getting that single record
2.
**$number** has data of phone number

```
return $db->update(array('$set' => array("PhoneNumbers.$.number" => $number)));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438362/adding-new-element-to-array-in-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) command to add multiple numbers to list

```
   model.update({'FirstName':'Mohammad'}, {$push:{PhoneNumbers: NumberInt(1234567890)}}, function (err, updatedModelObj) {
if (err) {
   console.log(err);

}
callback(updatedModelObj);

})
```

Comment: In your answer `{'FirstName':'Mohammad'},` will update this value as well or it is like `where` condition..?

Comment: I have tried with these $push,$set,$addtoset  and for query update,findmodify both none are working cant able to where I am doing wrong.!

Comment: Yes it is like where condition. Here  i have used mongoose update, if you can update code, i can check it - for more info http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html